Understanding useImperativeHandle vs Manual (Forwarded) Ref Handling
I'm trying to understand the difference between using useImperativeHandle and manually handling forwarded refs in an effect when working with callback refs. I encountered an infinite rendering loop when using useImperativeHandle, but the issue was resolved when handling the ref manually in an effect.
interface PanoramaHandle {
  updateView: (params: PanoramaConfig) => void;
  panorama: any;
}

interface Props {
  initialConfig?: PanoramaConfig;
}

const Parent = () => {
  const [panoramaRef, setPanoramaRef] = useState<PanoramaHandle | null>(null);
  
  return (
    <StreetView 
      ref={setPanoramaRef}
      initialConfig={// some initial config}
    />
  );
};

const StreetView = forwardRef<PanoramaHandle, Props>(({ initialConfig }, ref) => {
  const panoramaRef = useRef<any>(null);
  const updateView = useCallback((params: PanoramaConfig) => {
    panoramaRef.current?.update(params);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    panoramaRef.current = new Panorama(initialConfig);

    // Manual ref handling - this works
    if (typeof ref === "function") {
      ref({ updateView, panorama: panoramaRef.current });
    } else if (ref) {
      ref.current = { updateView, panorama: panoramaRef.current };
    }
  }, [initialConfig, updateView, ref]);

  // Using useImperativeHandle causes infinite loop, which makes sense.
  // useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
  //   updateView,
  //   panorama: panoramaRef.current,
  // }));

  return <div />;
});

Questions:

What's the proper way to handle this situation? When should I use useImperativeHandle vs manual ref handling?
Assume that instead of using an effect, we used a callback for the panoramaRef, but still wanted to forward it to the parent. How do callback refs interact with useImperativeHandle?

I understand that this might be related to the timing of when refs are set and how React handles updates, but I'd appreciate a clear explanation of the underlying mechanics. Thanks!
Edit:
After mucking around, it seems like the following code that uses a getter works. I think I'd still appreciate an explanation of my original two questions though!
const StreetView = forwardRef<PanoramaHandle, Props>(({ initialConfig }, ref) => {
  const panoramaRef = useRef<any>(null);
  const updateView = useCallback((params: PanoramaConfig) => {
    panoramaRef.current?.update(params);
  }, []);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, 
    () => ({
      updateView,
      get panorama() {
        return panoramaRef.current;
      }
    }),
    [updateView]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    panoramaRef.current = new Panorama(initialConfig);
  }, [initialConfig]);

  return <div />;
});

